# AzureBlobStorage Connector - CreateFile/DeleteFile - Id, relationship with Azure Storage Blobs client library for .NET

Tags: azure-blob-storage, powerapps, azure-sdk

I have a powerapp using the [AzureBlobStorage Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/)(the connector) . However, this app has to interact with data that is being bulk uploaded using the [Azure Storage Blobs client library for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.Storage.Blobs_12.6.0/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/README.md) (the api).

When you create a blob using **the connector** you get and Id which can then be used to Delete the blob.

However, when creating blobs with **the api** I cannot see how I can get that ID (you just use the blobid which is the filename).  Hence data that is being bulk created cannot be deleted in the Power App.

**The connector** returns a [BlobMetadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/#blobmetadata) object when calling [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/#create-blob).

**The api** returns a [BlobContentInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobcontentinfo?view=azure-dotnet) when calling [UploadBlob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.uploadblob?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_BlobContainerClient_UploadBlob_System_String_System_IO_Stream_System_Threading_CancellationToken_).  This metadata object does not contain an Id or anything matching the format of the BlobMetadata.ID.

Does anyone know how I can get this Id from **the API**?

Comment: I got nowhere with this, but I did find how to get the "Id" form PowerApps using the "container/blobname.ext".  You can call the [GetFileMetadataByPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/#get-blob-metadata-using-path).  This adds another web call, however, it allows ingration between Azure SDK and PowerApps/Flow

Answer (score 0):

You could get Blob metadata from [`BlobProperties.Metadata`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobproperties?view=azure-dotnet). This is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-properties-metadata?tabs=dotnet#set-and-retrieve-metadata) about setting and retrieving metadata using .Net.

```
// Get a reference to a container named "sample-container" and then create it
BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerName);

// Get a reference to a blob named "sample-file" in a container named "sample-container"
BlobClient blob = container.GetBlobClient(blobName);
await ReadBlobMetadataAsync(blob);

// Retrieve metadata
public static async Task ReadBlobMetadataAsync(BlobClient blob)
{
    try
    {
        // Get the blob's properties and metadata.
        BlobProperties properties = await blob.GetPropertiesAsync();

        Console.WriteLine(properties.BlobType);
        Console.WriteLine("Blob metadata:");
        

        // Enumerate the blob's metadata.
        foreach (var metadataItem in properties.Metadata)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\tKey: {metadataItem.Key}");
            Console.WriteLine($"\tValue: {metadataItem.Value}");
        }
    }
    catch (RequestFailedException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"HTTP error code {e.Status}: {e.ErrorCode}");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

You could also get metadata using Azure-CLI, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob/metadata?view=azure-cli-latest).

Comment: Unfortunatelly, the "Id" is also not in the BlobProperties, or the BlobProperties Metadata.  I justs did an enumeration of the Metadata values and its empty when using the SDK to upload.

Comment: @gatapia Maybe there are two Blob metadatas, one is for connector, another is BlobProperties.Metadata. It seems there is no SDK for the metadata of connector. You could try to call logic app to get file metadata using path, see [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/13415471-774a-4909-977b-e25d247fa911/call-logic-app-rest-api-from-c?forum=AzureAPIApps).