# Azure Blob Storage - how do I get the Blob Storage ID after uploading a blob?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using a C# Console Application (.NET Core 3.1) to read a load of image files from Azure Blob Storage and produce thumbnails of those images. The new images are to be saved back to Azure, and the Blob ID stored in our database. How do I find the ID of the items saved. Here is the command:

```
Azure.Response<BlobContentInfo> blobs = containerClient.UploadBlob(fileName, outStream);
```

I can't seem to find it in the returned object

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobcontentinfo?view=azure-dotnet

My original pictures were created and save using PowerApps, where the control does indeed return the Blob ID - see below:

```
 Set(
        gblSentBlob,
        AzureBlobStorage.CreateFile(
            Text(gblAzureFileContainer),
            GUID() & ".jpg",
            camControl.Photo
        )
    );
    If(
        !IsEmpty(gblSentBlob),
        Notify("Picture saved to Azure storage:" & gblSentBlob.DisplayName);
        UpdateContext({locFileName: gblSentBlob.DisplayName});
        UpdateContext({locAzureStorageID: Text(gblSentBlob.Id)}); // <- *** this is the Blob ID ***
        UpdateContext({locSavedToAzure: true});
```

Here, the AzureBlobStorage.CreateFile function returns an object which contains the ID I am looking for.

How do I get this ID in my Console Application.

A typical Blob ID looks like this:

```
JTJmc2hpcmVibG9iY29udGFpbmVyJTJmNTk3MzQ4NGYtNGVhNy00NzJkLTkyMzQtYWIwNzM5NWNlOGRiLmpwZw==
```

I can then retrieve the images for display using the following (in PowerApps)

```
AzureBlobStorage.GetFileContent(ThisItem.BlobStorageID)
```

My full code:

```
 var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);
                using Stream stream = await blobClient.OpenReadAsync();
                Image myImage = Image.FromStream(stream);
                Image myThumbnail = PictureProcessor.returnThumbnail(myImage);
                // now save this image
             
                string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                string fileName = guid + ".jpg";
                //create a memory stream ready for the rescaled image
                Stream outStream = new MemoryStream();
                
                myThumbnail.Save(outStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                Console.WriteLine(
                    "Length = {0}, Position = {1}\n",
                    outStream.Length.ToString(),
                    outStream.Position.ToString());

                outStream.Position = 0;
                Azure.Response<BlobContentInfo> blobs = containerClient.UploadBlob(fileName, outStream);

                Console.WriteLine("blobs RETURN OBJECT: " + blobs.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("blobs GetRawResponse: " + blobs.GetRawResponse());
                
                Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I am very curious how such an Id looks like. Blobs do not have a dedicated id other than the path, I think it is something that power apps generates or something. Can you post the example content? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63984830/azureblobstorage-connector-createfile-deletefile-id-relationship-with-azure

Comment: @PeterBons - I have added the detail to the original question.

Comment: @Dai - it is the C# code I am looking for, not the PowerApps stuff. The PowerApp is already working correctly thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I decoded this from Base64 and then into UTF-8:

```
JTJmc2hpcmVibG9iY29udGFpbmVyJTJmNTk3MzQ4NGYtNGVhNy00NzJkLTkyMzQtYWIwNzM5NWNlOGRiLmpwZw==
```

I got this:

```
%2fshireblobcontainer%2f5973484f-4ea7-472d-9234-ab07395ce8db.jpg
```

So your "Blob ID" appears to be the Base64-encoded representation of the UTF-8 (or 7-bit ASCII?) representation of the URL-encoded string value you're passing into `AzureBlobStorage.CreateFile`'s second parameter.

So do this:

```
String powerAppsBlobId = @"JTJmc2hpcmVibG9iY29udGFpbmVyJTJmNTk3MzQ4NGYtNGVhNy00NzJkLTkyMzQtYWIwNzM5NWNlOGRiLmpwZw==";

Byte[] blobIdBytes = Convert.FromBase64String( powerAppsBlobId );

String urlEncodedBlobName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString( bytes );

String actualBlobName = Uri.UnescapeDataString( urlEncodedBlobName );

Console.WriteLine( actualBlobName )
```

This program will then print this:

```
/shireblobcontainer/5973484f-4ea7-472d-9234-ab07395ce8db.jpg
```

Comment: you have hit the nail on the head. So all I need to do to find my ID is to start with "/shireblobcontainer/" + my filename and convert that back to Base64.

Comment: You need to UTF-8-encode it *before* encoding it with Base64.

Answer (score 1):

After posting my first answer (with the `Base64` decoding) [I took a look at the documentation for the Azure Blob connector for PowerApps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/#blobmetadata) and I see that the `BlobMetadata.Name` and/or `BlobMetadata.Path` values should contain the full blob-name too.

I don't know why you pointed to the documentation for `Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models`  as that's not for use by PowerApps.

So a better idea is to store the `Blob.MetadataPath` value when you upload the blob from within PowerApps, so your Console application can get to it - this is just in case PowerApps changes their "algorithm" for generating those Base64 BlobIds (e.g. they could include the blob version date+time, or shared access signatures, for example).

So change your code to this:

```
 Set(
        gblSentBlob,
        AzureBlobStorage.CreateFile(
            Text(gblAzureFileContainer),
            GUID() & ".jpg",
            camControl.Photo
        )
    );
    If(
        !IsEmpty(gblSentBlob),
        Notify("Picture saved to Azure storage:" & gblSentBlob.DisplayName);
        UpdateContext({locFileName: gblSentBlob.DisplayName});
        UpdateContext({locAzureStorageID: Text(gblSentBlob.Id)});
        UpdateContext({locAzureStoragePath: Text(gblSentBlob.Path)}); // <--- Add this here
        UpdateContext({locSavedToAzure: true});
```

Comment: I am not looking for a PowerApps answer. My question is about C# code for a Console App.

Comment: @SimpleSimon Your posting didn't say you couldn't change your PowerApps code - and as I mentioned in my answer, it's **best** if you do store the `Path` value in your PowerApps code because **there's no guarantee that `Id` will always be the Base64-encoded UTF8 of the URL-encoded blob name**.

Comment: yes, the images I create will be displayed in a PowerApp, which uses the BlobID in the format I gave to access the image file.